# WordPress Comment spam issue

Tags: theme-development, comments

I'm Trying to completely disable WordPress Comments. I have manually disabled comments via the WordPress back-end setting and I also created a new blank file called "no-comments-please.php" and then I added the below to my functions.php. Yet the comments show up in their numbers.

```
add_filter( 'comments_template', 'remove_comments_template_on_pages', 11 );
function remove_comments_template_on_pages( $file ) {
if ( is_page() )
$file = STYLESHEETPATH . '/no-comments-please.php';
return $file;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might as well go the whole nine yards & use [Disable Comments](http://wordpress.org/plugins/disable-comments/). In addition to a complete lock down, the plugin will remove any comment related sections in the admin.

Answer (score 0):

Comments can be enabled or disabled for each individual page and post.

The comments setting you've toggled already controls the default behavior for NEW pages/posts. It doesn't change the comments settings on pages/posts that already existed.

Go edit the Pages and Posts and turn off the ability to post comments on them individually.

All your code does is to not display the comments form. Spammers don't use the form, they send the data directly to the comments-posting file. You need to turn off the ability to receive comments so that nobody can comment on a given page/post.

Comment: I already did that Otto

Comment: If you had disabled comments on each post/page individually, then you wouldn't be able to get comments on them anymore, from any source.

Comment: That's really what's driving me crazy.

Comment: Did you also disable "pings"? These are known as pingbacks or trackbacks, and they can appear to be comments as well.